# Nginx logging. ( mp4 module used )

Tags: nginx, logging

I am having issues to understand what is happening in Nginx access log when using mp4 pseudo streaming.

Issue I am having is that when I access mp4 file on the server, Nginx still does not write anything in the log file.

My guess is because the file is not served 'till the end.

Once I stop the video or fast forward it or just close the browser the log is being written but with the current time stamp and not the time the video actually is accessed.

Besides "standard" config on Ubuntu 16.04 there is just MP4 module activated.

How can I achieve to log access to the video file when it actually happens?

Comment: I haven't played with that module, but there are various logging options that may address this. [Module ngx_http_log_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html).

Comment: The log file is being appended but  not at the "play" moment, but after any action afterwards.